# How to change a portion of Body background-color on mousemove?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to do something similar to Paint, when you color a page on mouse moving. This is what i did first :

```
 <script>
    $(document).mousemove(function(event){
    var cordX = event.pageX;
    var cordY = event.pageY;
    $("<div></div>").addClass("circle").appendTo("body").css({'top':cordY,'left':cordX});
    })
   </script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4o1xkp3d/1/

But spamming the body with many `<div>` is not an eficient method. So i think i can achieve the same result if i just color a portion of pixels on body background when i move the mouse cursour.Of course, at this moment i don't know how to continuously change body background-color to a couple of pixel size on specific position relative to mouse cursour. Any ideas?

Comment: [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)

Comment: Thanks for the hint but how can it be done the way i described ?